# TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable left join databricks

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

i am trying to left join two data frames by coding as below:

billing_classDF:

```
icp billing_class
0   0000033830DE8D0 RESI
1   0000044100DE8F8 RESI
2   0000033883DE6A2 RESI
```

alpeDF:

```
    Invoice No  Site    Load Group  Description Charge Month    From    To  Factor Description  Factor 1    Divisor 2   Factor 3    Factor 4    Amount Exclusive GST    Reversed Line
0   8888    0006472848AL9C1 015HCA  Distribution Fixed Charge   Oct-21  1/10/2021   31/10/2021  None    31  None    None    31  44.76   None
1   8888    0004943007ALFEB 015HCA  Distribution Fixed Charge   Oct-21  1/10/2021   31/10/2021  None    31  None    None    31  44.76   None
2   8888    0005350255AL270 LOWLCA  Additional LOW Variable Distribution Charge Oct-21  1/10/2021   31/10/2021  None    561 None    None    None    26.2    None
```

Code

```
alpe_billing_class=alpeDF.join(billing_classDF, alpeDF('Site')==billing_classDF('icp'), 'left')
```

I got error message:

> TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable

Comment: `alpeDF('Site')` -> `alpeDF['Site']`?

Comment: Thanks G.Anderson, tried your suggestion, and got an error message : ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects

Answer (score 0):

rename "Site" to "icp"

```
alpeDF=alpeDF.withColumnRenamed('Site','icp')
billing_class_alpe=alpe.join(billing_class, ['icp'],'left')
```

and it works. Cheers :D

Answer (score 0):

You should use square brackets instead of normal brackets:

```py
alpeDF.join(billing_classDF, alpeDF['Site']==billing_classDF['icp'], 'left')
```